# How to validate the type of a variable in a typescript-eslint custom rule

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am trying to write a custom typescript-eslint rule where i need to make sure that the callee's object of the node is of a specific Type which i'll just call `MyType` here. So i am using the typescript-eslint' CallExpression, as seen in the code below

Source code:

```
interface MyType {
   ...
}

const someVariable: MyType = ...;
```

custom typescript-eslint rule:

```
export const rule = createRule({
  name: 'some-name',
  meta: {
    type: 'problem',
    docs: {
      description: 'description',
      recommended: 'error',
    },
    schema: [],
    messages,
  },
  defaultOptions: [],
  create: (context) => {
    return {
      CallExpression(node: TSESTree.CallExpression) {
        const services = ESLintUtils.getParserServices(context);
        const checker = services.program.getTypeChecker();

        const callee = node.callee;
        const object = callee.type === 'MemberExpression' ? callee.object : null;

        if (object === null) {
          return;
        }

        const type = checker.getTypeAtLocation(services.esTreeNodeToTSNodeMap.get(object));

        const isMyType = (
          object.type === 'Identifier' &&
          (type as any)?.symbol?.escapedName === 'MyType'
        );

        if (isMyType) {
          [... do stuff here]
        }
      },
    };
  },
});
```

However, my problem is that the symbol or escapedName is undefined so it doesnt equal 'MyType'. Is there a (better) way to check if a callee's object is of a specific type?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Why can't this be expressed in typescript? It seems you're trying to write type restrictions not in the thing which is meant for that -- typescript, but instead inside of an eslint rule. Why? Maybe there's a legit reason but the use case would really help as it sets alarm bells ringing. Usually, such problems are solved in the architecture of the code, and not via linting.

Comment: What i am trying to do is to validate that a function call like `const test =(someString: string, ...values: any[]) =>{}` has an array values of length equal to the number of a given pattern in `someString`. For example if someString has 2 instances of '{}' then the values array should have a length of 2, meaning this would throw an error `test("something {} something {}", 10)`. However, i was unable to express something like that in a typescript type. I can easily add a runtime check, but it much rather get a compile time error.

Comment: Gotcha. This is possible through "typescript template literals" in typescript, which will give you a compile time error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, the problem can be solved purely in TS template literals without the need for an ESLint rule. The error will also be at compile time for invalid invocations. TS template literals allow TS to understand the construction of a statically analysable string.

One restriction here is the first arg must be provided directly, i.e. it can't be constructed through a variable which is composed of other strings. But this would also be true with the Eslint way.

```
type StringToTuple<S extends any, A extends any[] = []> =
  S extends `${string}{}${infer Rest}`
    ? StringToTuple<Rest, [...A, any]>
    : A;

const format = <S extends string>(inputStr: S, ...args: StringToTuple<S>): string  => {
  return inputStr // Do actual logic here
}

const result1 = format('something {} something {}', 10, 'two');  // OK
const result2 = format('something {} something {}', 'one', 'two', 'three');  // Compile error
const result3 = format('something {} something {} something {}', 'one', 'two', 'three');  // OK
```